# How can I stop a javascript function (poll) from being executed multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `poll()` function:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   poll(10);
   $("#refresh").click(function(){ poll(10); });
});

function poll(timeout){
   return setTimeout(function(){
      if (timeout == 10){
         timeout = 10000;
      }
      $.ajax({ url: "/ajax/livedata.php", success: function(data){
         $("#result").html(data);
         poll(timeout);
      }, dataType: "json"});
   }, timeout);
}
```

So, what happens there:

1) on page load, `poll()` is called and the loop starts being executed.

2) on `#refresh` click, `poll()` is called right at that moment to request new data immediately.

**The problem:** whenever I click `#refresh` to request new data, the `poll()` is called again, but fired multiple times (first time the initial + every new click). Thus it fires not every 10 seconds as expected, but multiple times every 10 seconds (depending on how many times I clicked on `#refresh`).

How can I fix this, so that whenever I click `#refresh`, only 1 instance will be left looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first store your `setTimeout` Object to a variable somewhat like this

```
var a = poll(10);
```

then stop it upon clicking refresh by using this code

```
clearTimeout(a);
```

So it will be like this

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   var a = null;   
   $("#refresh").click(function(){ 
      if(a != null){
           clearTimeout(a);
           a = null;
      }
      a = poll(10); 
   });
});
```

reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_stop

Comment: This look like exactly what I need, except that for some reason, clearTimeout(a) is unable to destroy the setTimeout object.

Comment: @RiMMER maybe @Mahan is thinking of `setInverval` / `clearInterval`

Comment: @RiMMER please check the references I put